# Django, returning file attachment as HttpResponse, can I get file size?

Tags: python, django, download, filesize

I am returning an Excel .XLS file from a weboage, like:

```
xls_response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
xls_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=funfile.xls'
.
.
<code to generate the file - already accomplished>
.
.
return xls_response
```

Everything is fine, but I'd like to see what the file size is before sending it, so I can show the file size the last time it was downloaded. I have a model already that will store this, but I need to figure out how to get the file size from the `xls_response object` before it is returned to the client. Is there a way to do this, other than perhaps just the `len()` of its binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see code below, remember django is just python

```
from sys

sys.getsizeof(obj[, default]) #returns size of a python object.
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof

Comment: Thanks, James. You pointed me in the right direction. I had to save `sys.getsizeof(xls_response.content)` for some reason the size of the object was not the full size of its content, but the `HttpResonse.content` is. Cheers!